# How do I use an object inside of a pointer as a query constraint?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a high score class and a pointer to the user class. Inside of that user class I have another pointer to the game class. I am trying to query the high score class where the game pointer inside the user class is equal to a value. Am I doing it correctly because it is not working?

```
var score = Parse.Object.extend("HighScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(score);
query.include("user");
query.include("user.game");
query.equalTo("user.game", game); //game is an object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually i would equalTo before i include. Also, i think you cant compare an object itself. you have to strip your query down.

Try this:

```
var score = request.object.get('HighScore');
var query = new Parse.Query(score);
query.equalTo("user.game", game);
query.include("user");
query.include("user.game");
query.first({...});
```